# CSS backdrop-filter not rendered in column layout

Tags: css, google-chrome

While trying to create a blur-on-hover effect, I noticed backdrop filters don't work in the context of a column layout - they are simply not rendered, unless a 3D transform is applied. The following code snippet illustrates the behaviour.

Why is this?

```css
.columns {
  columns: 3;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.overlay.overlay-fix {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
  <h1>#noFilter</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <h1>Filter</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea.
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
  <div class="column">
  <h1>Filter + 3D Transform</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea.
    <div class="overlay overlay-fix"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, using any translate will work, not just 3D translations. I still don't understand why.

Comment: not only a 3D transform but any transform (even a 2D one)

Comment: I see the blur on the second element in chrome, but not on either of the elements in firefox. Edit: just found out its not supported by default on firefox, my bad.